# When creating a widget with a button, how to specify an ID?

Tags: kivy, kivymd

So I already make an expanding list when pressing a button, the problem is that I can´t find I way to add an icon in the right part(as the sample one) of the `ListItem`

Code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineRightIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.list.list import IconRightWidget



Window.size = (300, 500)

navigation_helper = """

<DietScreen>:
    Screen:
    
        MDBoxLayout:
            
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: ("5dp", "65dp" , "5dp", "5dp")
            pos_hint: {"top": 1}
            
            MDScrollView:
                
                MDList:
                    id: box
                    OneLineRightIconListItem:
                        id: hola
                        text: 'testitem'
                        on_press:
                        IconRightWidget:
                            icon: "dots-vertical"
                              
                
        
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: "Nueva Dieta"
                md_bg_color: "white"
                text_color: "black"
                font_size: 16.2
                pos_hint: {"right": 1, "bottom": 1}
                on_press: root.buttonClicked()

Screen:
    


    MDNavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id: scr
            
            DietScreen:


"""



class DietScreen(MDScreen):
    
    def buttonClicked(self):
        
        
        newButt = OneLineRightIconListItem(text='Button')
        self.ids.box.add_widget(newButt)
    
    
class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        
        screen = Builder.load_string(navigation_helper)
        return screen

    
    
DemoApp().run()
```

I tried to specify an `id` to the `ListItem` created, and in the same method after addind the `ListItem`, add an `IconRightWidget` with an icon determined, but it results in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your:

```
newButt = OneLineRightIconListItem(text='Button')
```

With:

```
newButt = OneLineRightIconListItem(IconRightWidget(icon='dots-vertical'), text="Button")
```